# To identify which application uses kerberos authentication

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, kerberos

i need to identify which application / process requesting kerberos authentication.

Eg I have an PC for login i am using windows AD account. In that pc there are several applicationslike outlook, shared folder,IE,ect. they required AD authentication. i just need a script / tool to idenify which windows process / application all are required AD authentication.

Is it possible. can any one help.

Regards,

Karthick V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly a language issue, but typically you see servers and services *requiring* (or mandating) Kerberos authentication (and maybe allowing fallback to for instance NTLM) and client applications *supporting* Kerberos, but also supporting other authentication schemes.

Most of the times the application and server will *negotiate* to find an authentication method they both support.

Only when the negotiation concludes both application and server support Kerberos the application will request a Kerberos service ticket to authenticate itself (you) to that service.

That would make it difficult to scan your PC and determine beforehand if applications support Kerberos (AD authentication).